# Centering search from in header

Tags: html, css, centering

In my header, I have a logo top left that shouldn't move, and a search input form that I want to center horizontally (even when the browser resizes) but am finding hard to do so (the "Go" button should be next to it as well.

I attempted to auto margin and all but could not get this to work. I have included the code and a jsfiddle.

Thank you!

html:

```
<header>
  <h1 id="logo">Test Logo</h1>
  <form method="get" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" />
    <ul id="suggestions"></ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
  </form>
</header>
```

css:

```
body {
     font: 14px/1.5 "Open Sans", "PT Sans", "Source Sans Pro",
        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: #333;
    height: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

header {
    position: relative; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black; 
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#logo {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#ECF0F1;
    display:inline
}

#search {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    outline: none;
    display:inline;
}

#search-form input[type='submit'] {
    display:inline;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#ddd));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, #ddd);

}

#search-form {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/31zoco4c/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/31zoco4c/2/)

Changed **CSS**

```
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#ECF0F1;
    display:inline
}
#search-form {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display:inline;
}
```

What I have done is, I've set the display of your `header` to `inline-block` and used `text-align:center` for the `header`. Then, to make the `logo` stick to the left always, I have used `float:left`. And, to make the searchform centered, I set its `display` to `inline-block`.

Comment: Thank you! As a follow up, is there any way to center the search bar for the entire page? Right now it is centered slightly to the right since the logo offsets it. As well as having the "go" button directly to the right of the search bar

Comment: if you can remove the `<ul>` which is inbetween the search box and the button, then the button will always stick to the right of the search bar.See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/31zoco4c/3/)

Comment: Ok sounds good - the thing is that that <ul> will be the predictive search results for the search form. Is there a way it could be scaled so it remains right beneath the search input box?